# Pandas' Series.plot() stacks disjoint segments instead of adjoining them

Tags: python, pandas, windows, anaconda

I'm following the video from [2018 or 2019 on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-statistics-financial-analysis/lecture/mfHGK/1-3-basics-of-dataframe) that explains the basics of how to use `pandas`. The examples are based on the Facebook stock data that one can download in CSV format (e.g., from Yahoo Finance).

I came across a difference in how the `plot()` function works, and I can't figure out how to make it do what the video says it should be doing. According to them, and according to their screenshot (see below), when you plot multiple series for different x-axis values, you should end up with a continuous line chart, with the different segments colored differently.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

However, my version of `pandas` (presumably, 1.5.2) plots the separate segments on top of each other, even though that makes no sense. Is this a bug or a new feature introduced into `pandas` since 2018? Is there some argument to `plot()` that controls this behavior?

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd

fb = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\META.csv", index_col = 'Date')

fb.loc['2022-01-10':'2022-06-01', 'Close'].plot()
fb.loc['2022-06-02':, 'Close'].plot()
```

This is what I see plotted in my notebook (note the overlapping labels on the x-axis):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `Date` column as `DatetimeIndex`:

```
fb = pd.read_csv('META.csv', index_col='Date', parses_dates=['Date'])
```

Index as datetime:

[image]

Index as string:

[image]

Demonstration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Corralien's answer, I could also modify my `read_csv` call to pass `parse_dates = True` to automatically parse values as dates in the index column:

```
fb = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\META.csv", index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)
```

Comment: I also tried using the `dtype` argument, but I can't figure out how to correctly specify the `datetime` type as a `dtype`.

Comment: If you use `dtype={'Date': 'datetime64'}`, `read_csv` will raise a `TypeError` exception: `the dtype datetime64 is not supported for parsing, pass this column using parse_dates instead`.